# How to find a struct member using key-value semantic in c++?

Tags: c++, struct, boost

I am trying to implement a system such that I can traverse a tree of structs
using string name describing the field type. The main constraints for me are as
follows :-

1. Cannot modify the original struct, but can add macros or processing functions after the fact.
2. Has to be c++17 or lower.

The structs for e.g. are -

```
namespace example {

    struct Object1 {
        int32_t     member1;
        int32_t     member2;
        std::string member3;
    };

    struct Object2 {
        int32_t member1;
        int32_t member2;
        int32_t member3;
        Object1 member4;
    };

} // namespace example
```

I want to be able to traverse a nested struct like follows -

```
void do_some_operation(Object2 const& obj, std::string search_str) {
    auto result = obj[search_str];
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << '\n';
}
```

Where if `search_str = 'member1'`, I should get the value of member1 of Object2
instance, if `search_str = 'member4.member3'`, I should get the member3 of the
Object1 instance.

I know I can use boost reflections to achieve this somehow, but I do not have
any experience with this.

Comment: C++ has no reflection built in, so you either have to code it yourself (for three members), or use a library.

Comment: Sorry, but C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level.

Comment: What are you going to do? Maybe you're so used to having reflection you want to rebuild it in C++. But C++ works differently.

Comment: You say you cannot edit the class definitions. That is regrettable, because if you could, you could use macro magic to insert members into classes and pointers to them into maps. But as it is, my best bet would be to introduce a build step which *post-processes* the class definitions: Use a script language to parse the definitions and generate C++ code from them which creates the string->member maps. All other solutions are error prone (e.g. against typos) and hard to maintain (because a new member or changed member type would require changes in two places, without an alert if you forget).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica that's what Boost Describe does, non-intrusively. In fact, a subset is available without any macros, I just remembered: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html

Comment: I misremembered: PFR does [allow inspection of aggregates like tuples, but it doesn't supply member names](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html#boost_pfr.intro.out_of_the_box_functionality)

Comment: @sehe Well, the Boost Describe examples I looked at [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html) seemed to need to repeat the class members in macro calls like `BOOST_DESCRIBE_ENUM`, which seems logical and unavoidable. Ah, I see now that your answer amounts to the same. The PFR examples, by contrast, seem to be able to access class members without repetition (but also without name, as you say) which I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement it yourself. You can use Boost Describe to do the heavy lifting.

***Note**: I would consider using something that already implements most of what you need. You could consider Boost JSON which supports JSON Pointers - pretty close to what you want. You could even go the full length and use e.g. Boost Python or e.g. Lua bindings (like Sol2). In principle, avoid re-inventing the wheel*

### Using Boost Describe

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/005303c1247c7cae)**

```
#include <boost/describe.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bd = boost::describe;

namespace example {

    struct Object1 {
        int32_t     member1;
        int32_t     member2;
        std::string member3;
    };

    struct Object2 {
        int32_t member1;
        int32_t member2;
        int32_t member3;
        Object1 member4;
    };

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(Object1, (), (member1, member2, member3))
    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(Object2, (), (member1, member2, member3, member4))

    bool do_some_operation(int32_t i, std::string_view path) {
        bool valid = path.empty();
        if (valid) {
            std::cout << "Result: " << i << std::endl;
        }
        return valid;
    }

    bool do_some_operation(std::string const& s, std::string_view path) {
        bool valid = path.empty();
        if (valid) {
            std::cout << "Result: " << s << std::endl;
        }
        return valid;
    }

    template <typename T, typename D = bd::describe_members<T, bd::mod_public>>
    bool do_some_operation(T const& obj, std::string_view path) {
        bool valid = false;
        boost::mp11::mp_for_each<D>([&](auto descriptor) {
            std::string_view name(descriptor.name);
            if (path.starts_with(name)) {
                auto& subobj = obj.*descriptor.pointer;

                path.remove_prefix(name.length());
                if (path.starts_with("."))
                    path.remove_prefix(1);

                valid |= do_some_operation(subobj, path);
            }
        });
        return valid;
    }

} // namespace example

int main() {
    example::Object2 o { 111, 222, 333, { -111, -222, "Hello world" } };

    assert(do_some_operation(o, "member1"));
    assert(do_some_operation(o, "member2"));
    assert(do_some_operation(o, "member3"));
    assert(do_some_operation(o, "member4.member1"));
    assert(do_some_operation(o, "member4.member2"));
    assert(do_some_operation(o, "member4.member3"));

    assert(!do_some_operation(o, "member4"));
    assert(!do_some_operation(o, "member4.member4"));
    assert(!do_some_operation(o, "member5.member1"));
}
```

Prints

```
Result: 111
Result: 222
Result: 333
Result: -111
Result: -222
Result: Hello world
```

### Using Boost JSON

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e941caff0843c389)**

This converts the data into the equivalent JSON first:

```json
{
    "member1": 111,
    "member2": 222,
    "member3": 333,
    "member4": {
        "member1": -111,
        "member2": -222,
        "member3": "Hello world"
    }
}
```

And then uses JSON pointer to address subobjects. The syntax is a little different, but it implements goodies that you may need - like being able to return variant subobject types and handling/indexing into arrays.

```
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bj = boost::json;

namespace example {

    struct Object1 {
        int32_t     member1;
        int32_t     member2;
        std::string member3;
    };

    struct Object2 {
        int32_t member1;
        int32_t member2;
        int32_t member3;
        Object1 member4;
    };

    static inline void tag_invoke(bj::value_from_tag, bj::value& v, Object1 const& o) {
        v = {
            {"member1", o.member1},
            {"member2", o.member2},
            {"member3", o.member3},
        };
    }

    static inline void tag_invoke(bj::value_from_tag, bj::value& v, Object2 const& o) {
        v = {
            {"member1", o.member1},
            {"member2", o.member2},
            {"member3", o.member3},
            {"member4", bj::value_from(o.member4)},
        };
    }

} // namespace example

int main() {
    example::Object2 o { 111, 222, 333, { -111, -222, "Hello world" } };

    auto json = bj::value_from(o);
    std::cout << json.at_pointer("/member1") << "\n";
    std::cout << json.at_pointer("/member2") << "\n";
    std::cout << json.at_pointer("/member3") << "\n";
    std::cout << json.at_pointer("/member4/member1") << "\n";
    std::cout << json.at_pointer("/member4/member2") << "\n";
    std::cout << json.at_pointer("/member4/member3") << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
111
222
333
-111
-222
"Hello world"
```

Comment: Added both examples. You can even combine the two (as in the [Describe examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#example_to_json)) but I'll leave that as an exorcism for the reader.